# Change existing rows state in devexpress gridview in mvc explicitly via C# while binding data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I am able to add list of records in devexpress gridview in MVC. I am able to save modified records on save changes button in gird.

I have to mirror existing data in gridview which I am able to do using a html post button. Now grid having all new mirrored data in gridview which has loaded from C#, but save changes is not working here if user did not make any changes in grid data but my records are new, so is there any way to change states of rows as **new inserted rows** while binding data from C#?